# Get rows from a DataFrame by using a list of slices

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, indexing

I have a several million row data frame, and a list of interesting sections I need to select out of it. I'm looking for a highly efficient (read as: fastest possible) way of doing this.

I know I can do this:

```
slices = [slice(0,10), slice(20,50), slice(1000,5000)]
for slice in slices:
  df.loc[slice, 'somecolumn'] = True
```

... but that just seems like an inefficient way of getting the job done. It's *really* slow.

This seems faster than the for loop above, but I'm not sure if this is the best possible approach:

```
from itertools import chain
ranges = chain.from_iterable(slices)
df.loc[ranges, 'somecolumns'] = True
```

This also doesn't work, even though it seems that maybe it should:

```
df.loc[slices, 'somecolumns'] = True

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

My primary concern in this is performance. I need the best I can get out of this due to the size of the data frames I am dealing with.

Answer (score 10):

#### pandas

You can try a couple of tricks:

1. Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate `slice` objects into a single NumPy array. Indexing with NumPy arrays is usually efficient as these are used internally in the Pandas framework.
2. Use positional integer indexing via [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) instead of primarily label-based [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). The former is more restrictive and more closely aligned with NumPy indexing.

Here's a demo:

```
# some example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip('ABCD', np.arange(100).reshape((4, 25)))))

# concatenate multiple slices
slices = np.r_[slice(0, 3), slice(6, 10), slice(15, 20)]

# use integer indexing
df.iloc[slices, df.columns.get_loc('C')] = 0
```

#### numpy

If your series is held in a contiguous memory block, which is usually the case with numeric (or Boolean) arrays, you can try updating the underlying NumPy array in-place. First define `slices` via `np.r_` as above, then use:

```
df['C'].values[slices] = 0
```

This by-passes the Pandas interface and any associated checks which occur via the regular indexing methods.

Comment: What if you have already created list of slices and you want to use it with `pandas` and `np.r_`? Using directly `np.r_[slices]` will not work (not turning slices into arrays). I could do something like `np.concatenate([np.r_[s] for s in slices])` and then use it as index for pandas DataFrame. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are looking to slice on axis = 0 (row index). Instead of slices, I'm using numpy's `arange` method, and using `df.ix`:

```
slices = np.append(np.arange(0,10), np.arange(20,50), np.arange(1000,5000)) ##add other row slices here
df.ix[slices, 'some_col']
```

Comment: Note `ix` has been deprecated since v0.20.0. Use `loc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building a full indexer for the rows first, then do your assignment:

```
row_indexer = pd.concat((df.index[sub_slice] for sub_slice in slices), axis=0)
df[row_indexer, column] = True
```